# Why was this question closed as "unclear?"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[Can I use Trebuchet MS font for my manuscript on arvix?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/186435/can-i-use-trebuchet-ms-font-for-my-manuscript-on-arvix?noredirect=1)

I strongly disliked the question, but it seems to me that it is completely clear what is being asked.  The only visible "request" for clarification is pointing out a typo.

Why was this close reason used by four voters?

Comment: It's likely because the OP didn't clarify whether by _arvix_ they meant _arXiv_.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano To me, that was totally unambiguous.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist - well, the existence of viXra and the fact the OP is a high school student (making submission to arXiv somewhat more difficult) adds to the general uncertainty.

Comment: also, arvix was used throughout the question (4 times), so it is unlikely to have been a typo.

Comment: @Sursula-they- It's still a typo if you do it consistently.  I do not think it is plausible that the asker intended "arvix".

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/typo

Comment: @JonCuster Even if they meant viXra (not a plausible interpretation), it does not change the question.

Answer (score 6):

As noted in the comments, people presumably used this close reason because they were unclear whether "arvix" was supposed to be arXiv or something else.

Personally, I suspect they meant arXiv. I feel that the best practice would have been to:

- edit the question to correct this;
- edit the question to ask about "font requirements" generally, rather than a particular font;
- leave the question open / vote to reopen.

That said: I do not think this is a very valuable question generally, and since the OP did not respond to our requests for clarification, I presume it is not very valuable for them either. So, I personally do not think trying to salvage this question is a good use of my time. (Others may disagree, and can make these edits and vote to reopen if they like).

Based on your tone in the comments, I would suggest that this post was not made simply to ask for clarification; rather, you feel that these close votes were incorrect and in response, you would like us to....do something, I am not clear what. In future, I would suggest that you should (1) tell us upfront what proposal you are making, and (2) explain why you think the problem is of sufficient importance to merit a community-wide discussion rather than the usual vote-to-close/vote-to-reopen procedure.

Comment: The action I wanted you to take was to explain what happened and what should have happened, which you did well.  No further action is needed, in my opinion.

Comment: "explain why you think the problem is of sufficient importance to merit a community-wide discussion rather than the usual vote-to-close/vote-to-reopen procedure."  The usual procedure allows users to select the wrong close reason without explanation.  Discussion addresses that.  Also, this is not a community-wide discussion.